# Vertically center all characters after first character in word

Tags: css

Good day,

I wish to vertically center all remaining characters of a word after the first character for mainly using in Headings.

[a busy cat http://www.maiocv.com/TEST/stackoverflow.jpg](http://www.maiocv.com/TEST/stackoverflow.jpg)

CSS:

```
    .middletext {
        font-size:70%;
        vertical-align: top;
        line-height: 25%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <h1><span>C<span class="middletext">ustomer</span> B<span class="middletext">ilgewater</span></span></h1>
```

One of the issues I have is that when I use H2, the parent font sizes changes but the middle text isn't correctly aligned.

What can I do, is there a simpler method?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JV8LL/ fiddle of current code

Comment: would it not be easier to do it the other way round:http://jsfiddle.net/JV8LL/9/ or for better vertical alignment: http://jsfiddle.net/JV8LL/13/

Comment: damn too many ppl updating the same jsfiddle :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the font size of the first letter rather than the rest of it then you wouldn't need to bother with the line-height:

**HTML**

```
<h1>
    <span class="capital">C</span><span>ustomer</span> 
    <span class="capital">B</span><span>ilgewater</span>
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 span {vertical-align:middle;}
h1 .capital {font-size:120%;} /* or whatever size you want it to be*/
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JV8LL/13/)

Comment: This is a much more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/JV8LL/8/

Using this CSS:

```
span.firstletter { vertical-align: middle; }
.middletext {
        font-size: 70%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 25%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle, basically do it the other way round.

```
<h1><span class="uppertext">C</span>ustomer <span class="uppertext">B</span>ilgewater</h1>
```

and

```
.uppertext {
    font-size:150%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JV8LL/11/

Comment: This isn't right.  The top of the rest of the word is aligned to the top of the large letter.  Look closer.

Comment: @Michael The result of my fiddle is the same as the one you called elegant (checked quickly in Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: @wiesion Sorry, but no, they are not the same.  In your fiddle... The top of the L in Bilgewater aligns with the top of the B.  This is not centered, it should be slightly lower than that.  In mine, as well as the accepted answer they are truly centered.

Comment: For further technical clarification...  You are leaving the end of each word set to baseline, which changes based on line-height.  You are ONLY centering the first letter, and not centering both the first letter AND the rest of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `::first-letter` Selector instead  separating first letter to tag. (sorry it have to be block element not inline - span)

Comment: That will only do the first letter of the first word

Comment: Yes but it is still better to have tags per word than <span>C<span class="middletext">ustomer</span>.

Comment: True, as long as the selector is changed to something like `h1 > span:first-letter {`

Comment: @Alex Selector are slower than classes then i would suggest to just add class for span (but actually it cannot be span it have to be block element)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/JV8LL/3/

if you set `line-height: 150%;` it seems to work well.

Comment: Actually the `line-height` should always be equal to the `font-size` used for the title.